# Creating TIN raster from point layer from Google Earth in QGIS?

Tags: point, google-earth, tin, qgis-2.14

I created height layer from google earth from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bLbY3iMBW-A. The attribute table of the layer is:

[image]

The "ALT" field is the height from. My problem is when i try to create a TIN raster there is no option to choose the ALT field. The only options to choose is the xy coordinates. Why is it?

[image]

The QGIS 2.14 can recognized the ALT field, because when test the layer and create categorized style- the QGIS create it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the field type of ALT is not numeric. Interpolation plugin lists only numeric fields in the *Interpolation attribute* list. First check the field type in the layer properties dialog (right click on the layer name and properties from the menu and select fields tab). I suppose it is string.
[image]
Use the field calculator to convert text data into a new numeric field.
Make your layer editable, open the attribute table, click on Field calculator icon and fill the form like this:
[image]
Now you will see the *Z* column in the Interpolation plugin (I hope so).